# How to review thumbnails for photos on file browser?

Tags: thumbnails, photo

On Ubuntu 20.04, I can't see thumbnails for photos on the file browser. Appears only an image icon for each file. How to get thumbnails instead of icons?

Comment: This problem is similar to yours, try this:
[Why I can't see the thumbnails in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211843/why-i-cant-see-the-thumbnails-in-nautilus)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Or this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304583/looking-at-pictures-in-my-pictures-file